# How to call a function within a named template data binding in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I am using a named template to generate the html for an object hanging off my view model.  This works fine.

One of the properties of my object is a date in UTC.  I would like to convert that date to the timezone of the users browser before the html is generated.

I can listen to the afterRender event and set the html element value then, but I'm curious  if a cleaner way exists?

in my template I was wondering how to do the following...?

```
 <div data-bind="text: 'CreatedOn: ' + localizeDate(CreatedOn);"</div>
 ....
 function localizeDate(dateTolocalize)  {.... };
```

I have searched the documentation but couldn't find it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow i'm an idiot!  It appears you can easily call functions within a template, just don't include the semi-colon at the end of your statement.

```
<div data-bind="text: 'CreatedOn; ' + localizeDate(CreatedOn)"></div>
```

That works well :-)